# How can I test my webpage using phone gestures on desktop?

Tags: html, debugging, mobile, browser, desktop

I'm having a problem with my webpage where it doesn't scroll on phones.

This is not my problem though.  My problem is that it only happens on phones, and I need to debug is, but have no desire to debug from a cell phone (whether or not that's an option).

In firefox, I've tried using "Simulate touch events," but apparently (and I think this is a design flaw) that does not mean that clicking and dragging equates to the swipe gesture.

So how do I test my webpage with phone gestures on desktop?

Comment: You on a mac or PC? Mac you can use the simulators in xcode (free from app store). It's very straight forward. PC you can download any number of simulators for eclipse, though I haven't done that in so long I forget the details. Basically, use actual simulators or at least one real phone, whether or not you have no desire to do so. Thems the breaks with developing.

Comment: Do you know you can debug it from desktop:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/device-mode/

Comment: @KaiQing downloading a 2gb app and emulating a cell phone because "thems the breaks" is perhaps a concept worth revaluation.

Comment: No it isn't. That's like saying an actual editor like sublime is pointless when you can use dreamweaver and build a site with UI. Use the tools at your disposal, especially if the only cost is hard drive storage. Or if you feel like guessing, go right ahead. Those simulators save us tons of dev hours. If you don't have time to do it right, you have to have time to do it over

Answer (score 0):

> Try these:

1.You could use a simulator specific to your phone's os.. for example Bluestacks for android.

2.Go to firefox and press Shift+F8

3.Press Ctrl+Shift+M on Chrome